# NullPointerException in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

this is JDBC code for customized connection. I am using my sql 5 database server that is working properly.i have tried this code on net beans version 7.3. it contain 3 classes

```
public class MyDbOperation {

    private static Connection c;
    private static Statement st;
    private static ResultSet rs;
    private static ArrayList al;
    private static int m;
    private static Student student;
    static {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            c=  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/stp13","root","@Ashish123");
            st=c.createStatement();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public static int getInsert(Student s) throws SQLException {
      m=st.executeUpdate("insert into student values("+s.getRollNo()+",'"+s.getFname()+"','"+s.getLname()+"','"+s.getEmail()+"',"+s.getMob()+",'"+s.getStreet()+"','"+s.getCity()+"')");
        return m;
    }    
}
```

when i executed the code i get following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at stp13.MyDbOperation.getInsert(MyDbOperation.java:44)
at stp13.Stp13hbt.main(Stp13hbt.java:24)
```

whts wrong with the code? how to resolve?

Comment: the stacktrace is clear, show the line and see if one or variables involved there could be null... no magic needed, st sure is null.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    c=  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/stp13","root","@Ashish123");
    st=c.createStatement();
} catch(Exception e){}
```

You don't rethrow or log your exception so it is swallowed. `st` is then `null`. Change this to

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    c=  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/stp13","root","@Ashish123");
    st=c.createStatement();
} catch(Exception e){
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
}
```

Your code is full of memory leaks and SQL injection opportunities. Please *please* **please** read [a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) on the correct usage of JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you swallow an exception in your static initializer, so `st` is null. This is why you should never swallow exceptions. Add in a simple `e.printStackTrace()` and see what it says. Perhaps MySQL is not running.